# How to change a value when a list object is selected

Tags: excel, vba, list

I have a master list of products and stock counts (see image below), but I want for when a product is selected (on another sheet) for the stock count to be subtracted by 1.

[Example data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs05M.png)

What is the best way of doing this? (I tired a bit of VBA but didn't get too far)

Edit:

Here is how my mind would picture it working:
[How I picture how it would work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRDK8.png)

Comment: Just use an `IF()` formula that says "It the drop down cell is the item, 4-1, else 4"? what have you tried? Why do you need VBA?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BruceWayne The 4 wouldn't be static though so I'm not sure how I would handle that? Unless I could reference the cell? Ill try that now

Comment: It's not very clear - are those numbers in the "Stock" column the result of a formula? Can you expand a little on how the data is set up and what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: use `=INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(D2,A2:A6,0))` to find the number of the matching item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Basic VBA Example.

The `Worksheet_Change` event needs to be on the sheet that contains the dropdown.

Just check to see if the address of the changed cell is the address of your dropdown. You can use a named range or you can just use a static address as I did below.

I gave the list a named range called `Items` which we can reference.

Please note that on a separate sheet, you would need to use `Sheets("SheetName").Range("Items")`

I also used a simple `For Each` loop to check the values in the list - it may be better if it gets large enough to use a dictionary, variant array, or `Find`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$H$4" Then
    Dim c
    For Each c In Range("Items")
        If c = Target.Value Then
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
End If
End Sub
```

[image: Example]